# What's the enter key code for a char array?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a Reddit Formatter tool for whenever you have a text with just one line break to add another and make a new paragraph. Here in StackOverflow it's the same, you have to press the enter key twice to start a new paragraph. It'd go from:

```
 Roses are red
 Violets are Blue
```

to

```
 Roses are red

 Violets are Blue
```

It's actually pretty easy, and I've managed to do this code below by myself (probably messy, but it works!!) which for the moment replaces the 'a' characters from the textBox to 'e' after pressing a button.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Char[] textBox1Array = textBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox1Array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (textBox1Array[i] == 'a')
            {
                textBox1Array[i] = 'e';
            }
        }
        textBox1.Text = String.Concat(textBox1Array);
    }
```

The real question is: how do I use the enter key instead of 'a'? HTML code obviously doesn't seem to work:

```
(&#13;)
```

and with

```
\r\n
```

it throws another error because it doesn't consider it a single character (too many characters in character literal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight forward answer would be:

```
textBox1Array[i] = '\n';
```

another possibility would be to use the decimal code of new line:

```
textBox1Array[i] = Convert.ToChar(10);
```

it will automatically feed back the cursor

You could actually use the string directly without any conversion into an unflexible array. Use a reverse for-loop and access the chars with the `[ ]` operator, (because string is internally represented as a char-array):

```
string g = "Roses are red \r\nViolets are Blue";

for (int i = g.Length -1; i >=  0; i--)
{
    if (g[i] == '\n')
    {
        g = g.Insert(i, Environment.NewLine);
        // or as a string you can use your former logic
        g = g.Insert(i, "\r\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It was easier all the time. But how do I apply what you said?   {{{{textBox1Array[i] = '\n' + Environment.NewLine;}}}} doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Glow8 you are welcome, you can manipulate the string directly using the `Insert` method. It will return a new string. This way you can use your former logic of the 2 characters, or simply the C# given variable `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: Thank you very much! I have now two different solutions, I wish I could at least upvote you both now or give two valid answers. Thanks for everything :))))

Answer (score 1):

A linebreak is not necessarily the same on all systems. So if a user entered his text on Windows the linebreak could lok other than if the text was entered under Linux. So `Environment.Newline` won't work here. You need to check for several line break types. I would recommend to do the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\r")
                                 .Replace("\n\r", "\r")
                                 .Replace("\n", "\r")
                                 .Replace("\r", "\r\n\r\n");        
}
```

This way you will replace all (at least the ones I know) possible line break types with a placeholder and then replace that placeholder with a double linebreak (In this case the Windows version).

Comment: Very good idea but your code actually does nothing, it doesn't throw an error but it does nothing. I'll try with replace and see If I'm able to fix it

Comment: I've edited my answer. Forgot to to do the assignment of the result. Sorry

Comment: Woah it works now. My bad, actually for not noticing it haha. Incredible, thank you very much! I was breaking my brain with weird loops and It's just a string property in the end

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems the question is about what character stands for enter key, so I'll try answer that.

In my case it was `'\r'`. To make sure, try this code:

```
// you need to add textBox1 to try it or just use what's inside the method
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyChar == '\r')
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

Set a breakpoint on the `if` line, run the program and press `Enter`, when it stops on breakline add watch on `e` and look into its fields. You'll see what character is under `e.KeyChar`.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, is that you want where ever your program
intercepts a single newline character it should start a new
paragraph (i.e. "end of a line then a new line + new line).

I suggest two ways to achieve this,
1> On click of a button
2> when user hits the 'Enter/Return' key on keyboard
it should add a new paragraph just like in "MSWord"

For this test, I have put 2 textboxes, TextBox1 , TextBox2,
one command button (btnFormat) that would only work on TextBox1.

following is the code:

```
private void btnFormat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) == true) return;

    //searches for the new line character
    Int32 i = textBox1.Text.IndexOf("\r\n");
    Int32 j = 0;

    if (i == -1) return; //new line character not found

    String strA = "";
    String strB = "";

    //now pass the value in 'i' to 'j'
    Int32 icnt = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        //j : from where search should begin. Therefore, it is set
        //to a position ahead of last occurence of new line charachter(\r\n)
        //i.e. value in 'i'
        //i : current occurence of new line character

        //scan for the next occurence of new line character from
        //current positon
        i = textBox1.Text.IndexOf("\r\n",j);
        if (i == -1) break;

        //there is a possibility of some space(s) or no character at all
        //between the last position and current position, then in such a 
        //case we will remove that newly found new line characters so that
        //the formatting is uniform

        //all text before new line 
        strA = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, i);
        //all textbox after the new line
        strB = textBox1.Text.Substring(i + 2);

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text.Substring(j, i - j)) == 
        false)
        {
            textBox1.Text = strA + "\r\n\r\n" + strB;
            j = i + 4;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = strA + strB;
            //do not change the value of 'j'
        }
    }

    //increment i and now again scan from this position
    //for another new line character        
}
```

Case2:[when entering text or in a previously entered texts]
when user hits the 'Enter/Return' key on keyboard,
like in MSWord, the program automatically start a new paragraph (i.e.
Add two new line characters (\r\n\r\n).

```
private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
    {
        e.KeyChar = '\0';//this will suppress current {Return key}

        Int32 i = textBox2.SelectionStart;//your current cursor position
        String sa = textBox2.Text.Substring(0,i);//text before this pos.
        String sb = textBox2.Text.Substring(i);//text beyond from this pos
        textBox2.Text = sa + ("\r\n\r\n") + sb;
        textBox2.SelectionStart = i + 2;
        //if there is already one or more new line characters, then 
        //this code does not check for that, so it has to be removed
        //manually using 'delete' or 'backspace'
    }
}
```